# regex to delete same parts from a huge document with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a text of 3 million lines of this format

```
> Dyskeratosis congenita
>        DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 1" title="DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 1">  DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL  DOMINANT 1>
>        DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 2" title="DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 2">  DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL  DOMINANT 2>
>        DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 3" title="DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 3">  DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL  DOMINANT 3>
>        DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 4" title="DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 4">  DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 4>
>        DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 6" title="DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT 6">  DYSKERATOSIS CONGENITA AUTOSOMAL  DOMINANT 6>
```

i want to delete each part starts with "title= to >
i couldnt fix a regex to use in notepad ++

Comment: There are 2 '>' on each line. Up to which do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RegEx to find matches:

```
".+>
```

I don't know notepad++ but all you have to do now is replace with an empty string.

Edit:
If you want to match the first '>', then use this:

```
"".+\">
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match everything starting with (and including) "title=" and until the first > after the closing double quote

> title=\"[^\"]+\">